# kamailio - modify URI of incoming INVITE

Tags: sip, kamailio

is it possible to redirect all incoming calls to one specific sip account? I already did this with Asterisk adding line

`exten => _[1-9]XXX,1,DIAL(SIP/3000)`

to extentions.conf and now I am looking for the way how to do the same in Kamailio. But I am not experienced in Kamailio and I am not sure how to accomplish this goal. Should I modify Routing Logic section in kamailio.cfg or should I use some module like dialplan.so, uac.so or some similar one?

I am using Kamailio 5.4.4 and MariaDB 10.3.

I would appreciate any help

Thank you

Update 1: I tried to use module uac.so and function `uac_replace_to`.

In Global parameter section, I loaded module using `modparam ("rr", "append_fromtag", 1)` and `loadmodule "uac.so"`.
In Routing Logic, I modified

```
if (is_method("INVITE")) {
 setflag(FLT_ACC);
}
```

to

```
if (is_method("INVITE")) {
 uac_replace_to("","sip:3000@192.168.20.199");
 setflag(FLT_ACC);
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible

see sample kamailio file

https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/blob/master/etc/kamailio.cfg

in route PSTN near line 938

If you need forward to account registered on kamailio, see route LOCATION

Unfortanly kamailio is not asterisk and you need do handling for all other sip messages too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did not want to compare Asterisk and Kamailio as same systems, I just want to demonstrate what I want to achieve. In my laboratory enviroment, I have one computer representing few clients (ten clients). This computer is connected to the server with Kamailio and the server is connected to another computer with the sip client 3000. Whole communication is within this network and I need to redirect every call to client 3000 (even those which are not directly designated for this account).

Comment: So far, I used default script kamailio.cfg. In header, I defined `WITH_MYSQL, WITH_USRLOC, WITH_DEBUG` and I tried to use the function `uac_replace_to`, as I mentioned above. Later, after your advice, I tried to define `WITH_PSTN` and use command `uac_replace_to` in PSTN route. However, this didn't work. I would appreciate further help with this issue.

Comment: Why you use uac_replace? PSTN route ALREADY have all needed. Look. Kamailio is not something that can be used without understanding,sorry.

Comment: Based on your answer I thought, that I was at the right way with the command which I used, but I forgot to take care for another routes, which are needed for correct call forwarding. So I decided to try it in PTSN route as well.